# jquery mobile 1.4 not updating content on page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile

From the index page, a user clicks a navigation link, the data attribute is passed via ajax, the data is retrieved from the server but the content is not being updated on the new page.

Been stuck for hours, really appreciate any help!

js

```
$('a.navLink').on('click', function() {
var cat = $(this).data("cat");
console.log(cat);
$.ajax({
    url:        'scripts/categoryGet.php',
    type:       'POST',
    dataType:   "json",
    data:       {'cat': cat},
    success:    function(data) {
                    var title           = data[0][0],
                        description     = data[0][1];
                        console.log(title);
                    $('#categoryTitle').html(title);
                    $('#categoryTitle').trigger("refresh");
                    $('#categoryDescription').html(description);
                    $('#categoryDescription').trigger("refresh");
    }
});
});
```

Im getting the correct responses back on both console logs, so I know the works, but neither divs categoryTitle or categoryDescription are being updated.  I've tried .trigger('refresh'), .trigger('updatelayout') but no luck!

Comment: I would expect to see some change with the code you've shown. Are you 100% sure the selectors for the elements you want to update are correct?

Comment: Yes.  Using the above code, it will work, but then if I hit the back button and click another category link, it won't work. Or it will work a couple of times going back and forth, but then stop working.  But I do get the correct console.log responses every time.

Comment: It must have something to do with the page transition, because when I set up the same situation (without navigating away) and update a div on the same page as the link I get the expected results.

Comment: What type of contents are you updating? Pls share your html.

Answer (score 0):

This was not intended to be an answer (but I can't comment yet.. (weird SO rules)

You should specify in the question description that the above code IS working, that your problem occurs WHEN your playing back and forth on that page/code *aka, using the JQM ajax navigation*.

From what I understood in the above comment, you're probably "stacking" the ajax function every time you return to the page, thus getting weird results, if nothing at all.

Is your example code wrapped into something ? If not, (assuming you use JQM v1.4) you should consider wrapping it into `$( 'body' ).on( 'pagecontainercreate', function( event, ui ) {...` which I'm trying to figure out myself how to best play with..

Simple solution to prevent stacking the ajax definition would be to create/use a control var, here is a way to do so:

```
var navLinkCatchClick = {
  loaded: false,
  launchAjax: function(){
    if ( !this.loaded ){
      this.ajaxCall();
    }
  },
  ajaxCall: function(){
    // paste you example code here..

    this.loaded = true;
  }
}
navLinkCatchClick.launchAjax();
```

Comment: also, you should get ride of the `trigger()` if not necessary